# Creating a Slideshow where the user can input their own URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I am creating a slideshow where the user can enter their own url and it will change that image to the user url. The images will loop when the user press the start button. I would like to modify the code below so that there is only one image at a time (the new image replace the old image at the same location, not adding more). I would also like to add a caption to the image.

```js
   function myFunction() {
   
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    
    var y = document.getElementById("yourText").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
    
    var z = document.getElementById("hisText").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
    
    var total_images = 3;
    var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*total_images));
    var random_img = new Array();
    random_img[0] = document.createElement("IMG");
    random_img[0].setAttribute("src", x);
    random_img[0].setAttribute("width", "304");
    random_img[0].setAttribute("width", "228");
    random_img[0].setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock ");
    
    random_img[1] = document.createElement("IMG");
    random_img[1].setAttribute("src", y);
    random_img[1].setAttribute("width", "304");
    random_img[1].setAttribute("width", "228");
    random_img[1].setAttribute("alt", "The Solid Rock ");
    
    random_img[2] = document.createElement("IMG");
    random_img[2].setAttribute("src", z);
    random_img[2].setAttribute("width", "304");
    random_img[2].setAttribute("width", "228");
    random_img[2].setAttribute("alt", "The Heavy Rock ");
    
    document.body.appendChild(random_img[random_number]);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ++c
       
   }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
    <script src ="slideshow">
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>


  <input type="text" id="myText" value="https://bower.io/img/bower-logo.png">
  <input type="text" id="yourText" value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Vanamo_Logo.png">
  <input type="text" id="hisText" value="http://media.vectormagic.com/tutorials/revectorize/soldier.png">

  <p>Click the "Try it" button to get the text in the text field.</p>

  <button onClick="myTimer = setInterval(myFunction, 1000)">Start Slideshow!</button>
  
  <p id="demo">Click on the button above and I will count forever.</p>

  <button onClick="clearInterval(myTimer)">Stop Slideshow!</button>


  <p id="demo"></p>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do Something like this .... but thats not really a good option to build a slider ... makes more sense to user CSS3 etc... but its not that easy

```js
function loadRandomImage() {
     var randomImages = [];
     var myTextImage = document.getElementById("myText").value;
     var yourTextImage = document.getElementById("yourText").value;
     var hisTextImage = document.getElementById("hisText").value;
     var random_number;
     randomImages.push(createImage(myTextImage, "The Pulpit Rock"));
     randomImages.push(createImage(yourTextImage, "The Solid Rock"));
     randomImages.push(createImage(hisTextImage, "The Heavy Rock"));
        random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()) * randomImages.length); //take the array length
        document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML = randomImages[random_number].outerHTML;
}

function createImage(src, altTag) {
 var newImage = document.createElement("IMG");
 newImage.setAttribute("src", src);
 newImage.setAttribute("width", "304");
    newImage.setAttribute("width", "228"); //Overwrites the first width attribute
    newImage.setAttribute("alt", altTag);
    return newImage;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" value="https://bower.io/img/bower-logo.png">
<input type="text" id="yourText" value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Vanamo_Logo.png">
<input type="text" id="hisText" value="http://media.vectormagic.com/tutorials/revectorize/soldier.png">

<p>Click the "Try it" button to get the text in the text field.</p>

<button onClick="myTimer = setInterval(loadRandomImage, 1000)">Start Slideshow!</button>

<p id="demo">Click on the button above and I will count forever.</p>

<button onClick="clearInterval(myTimer)">Stop Slideshow!</button>


<p id="slider"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am doing this as a test and I wanted to use html and JavaScript only. Most other tutorial would include other languages but you were a very good help.

Comment: Vote up my answer if it helps 